# Changing Page Title while "in_category"

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, page-title

So I'm not sure what happened but this was working until the update to Wordpress 4.7. Can someone please help me figure out why my page header is still showing default "News & Events" when on any single post?

```
  if( $subheader_show ){
                        echo '<div id="Subheader" style="'. $subheader_style .'">';
                            echo '<div class="container">';
                                echo '<div class="column one">';

                                    // Title
                                    $title_tag = mfn_opts_get( 'subheader-title-tag', 'h1' );
                                    if( in_category('news' || 'community' || 'events')) {
                                    echo '<'. $title_tag .' class="title">News & Events</'. $title_tag .'>';
                                    } elseif( in_category('attorneys')) {
                                    echo '<'. $title_tag .' class="title">Attorneys</'. $title_tag .'>';
                                    } elseif( in_category('publications')) {
                                    echo '<'. $title_tag .' class="title">Publications</'. $title_tag .'>';
                                    } else {
                                    echo '<'. $title_tag .' class="title">'. mfn_page_title() .'</'. $title_tag .'>';
                                    }

                                    // Breadcrumbs
                                    if( $breadcrumbs_show ) mfn_breadcrumbs( $breadcrumbs_link );

                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`in_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) function incorrectly.
It accepts `int`, `string` or `array`. In your case it should be `in_category(array('news', 'community', 'events'))`. I have no clue how it was working before, because nothing changed with this function in 4.7 as far as I can see.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how it worked before either. But somehow it had been working for 2 months since I first made the edit. All of a sudden, today I noticed the headers were back to default. Nothing else changed, but tweaking the array worked. Thanks!!

Comment: `'news' || 'community' || 'events'` => `1` ,,, so presumably it would be equivalent to `in_category(1)`...